# Pattern callback not called by CGFillRect

Tags: ios, design-patterns, cgcontext

I've got a pattern to draw at various points in a canvas.  When I decide to CGFillRect() a rect starting at (0,0), the callback gets invoked correctly and the pattern gets painted.  When I decide to CGFillRect() at another point on the canvas (say, (0, 16)), the callback does not get called.

There must be some early-out logic inside CGContextFillRect() that decides not to fill that rect (or at least not call my callback), but i can't figure out what it is.  I could see discarding rects that are outside the canvas' bounds, but that is not the case with the coordinates I am filling.

The pattern itself is just 8 pixels by 16 pixels.  The rects I pass to CGContextFillRect() are the same size (so it will draw 1 tile exactly).

I'm hoping someone here can help me avoid debugging FillRect()'s logic in assembly.